# Google Map Not Shown Marker when Use LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin

I just learn `Kotlin` in the past week. I have learnt to create a map app and am able to show a marker when the point clicked. Unfortunately, I tried to create a `LiveData` to retrieve a map bookmark from the database and I get stuck getting the Marker shown with my code.

On my android debugger, I am pretty sure that the LiveData method is working because on `displayAllBookmarks` method (please refer to below code), receive all the data from database. And every I added a new bookmark on the map, the LiveData is called. So I think nothing wrong with the LiveData.

Here is my code to show the Marker on my Map

**onMapReady() method**

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = GoogleMap

    ------------- Bunch of method --------------

    createBookmarkMarkerObserver()

}
```

**LiveData Method `createBookmarkMarkerObserver()`**

```
private fun createBookmarkMarkerObserver() {
    mapsViewModel.getBookmarkMarkerViews()?.observer(
        this, { it ->
        it?.let {
            displayAllBookmarks(it)
        } 
    )
}
```

**Iterate Bookmark result `displayAllBookmarks(bookmarks)`**

```
private fun displayAllBookmarks(bookmarks: List<MapsViewModel.BookmarkMarkerView>) {
    bookmarks.forEach { it ->
        addPlaceMarker(it)
    }
    Log.e("Marker", bookmarks.toString())
}
```

**Adding place marker `addPlaceMarker(MapsViewModel<BookmarkMarkerView>)`**

```
private fun addPlaceMarker(
    bookmark: MapsViewModel.BookmarkMarkerView): Marker? {
    val marker = mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
        .position(bookmark.location)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
        .alpha(0.8f))
    marker.tag = bookmark
    return marker
}
```

**for the `MapsViewModel.BookmarkMarkerView` it is only data class like bellow**

```
data class BookmarkMarkerView(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var location: LatLng = LatLng(0.0,0.0)
)
```

If any additional information is needed for this, please just inform me.

**Big Thanks**

Comment: I doubt your problem is related to livedata, have you hardcoded values and sent them to marker in your map without livedata ? Also `addPlaceMarker()` function returns a `Marker` but it's not being used anywhere, why ?

Comment: Hi @SharpEdge, You are right, after i compare the stored number at my DB with the location Latitude Longitude, the number is different. On the Mapping of Bookmark i accidentally set the Latitude with Longitude. Thank You